# Android: Activity is destroy when pick image from gallery

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gallery

Currently I have an issue, the activity is destroyed and recreated when I back from gallery.
Here is the steps:

1. From "photo fragment", I start intent to pick image from gallery:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_IMAGE);
   ```
2. In gallery, I choose "camera" folder, then press hard "Home" button. To go to Home screen of device.
3. Open camera app and capture an image.
4. Go to my app (current from Gallery), and pick the image captured from step 3.

   ---> Then app's activity is destroyed and re-created again. It's cause the screen is mixed of 2 fragment's screen: The UI of "photo fragment" and "home fragment".

Do you know how my activity is re-created? and how to fix it?
I spent almost a day for this but it's still have no result.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: put up your activity classes and exception received in logcat

Comment: It don't have any exception, just call onDestroy(), then call onCreate() again. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct in that it destroys the activity and recreates when you come back from Image Picker. You need to save and restore your activity state using the following methods.

Save -> [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) 
Restore -> [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

More Refs -> [Recreating Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

You can do the same for Fragments as well by using [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) to save and [onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) to restore state.

Comment: my activity has viewpager which has several fragments. one of the fragment is starting an intent for picking images. `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               i.setType("image/*");
               getActivity().startActivityForResult(i,ACQUIRE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);`. after geting the image or clicking back or cancel from the activity that resolved the intent e.g gallery, my activity layout is destoryed. **it's not re-created since i have set some log code to be printed in onCreate() but they aren't printed.**

Comment: Is you onActivityResult getting called?

Comment: yes, it's been called and i can get the image that i picked from gallery. but between clicking the image in the gallery and the image appearing in my fragment in my viewpager, **my activity becomes blank for more for some  time. i have a background image which i have set to my activity and it's the only one been shown!. viewpager disappears and all other views below it**

Comment: Its the same issue. Your activity is getting killed. Attach your phone to Android Studio and in android monitor check the process it should show up as DEAD when your camera is started.